# Web App gets wrong IP after Windows Server upgrade

Tags: windows, apache, web-applications

We cloned the servers, upgraded to a newer version of the OS (Windows 2012) which is compatible with the web app. However, when we placed those servers in production, only the one with the load balancer was being accessible through the IP. The other 4 were not because the load balancer was trying to redirect traffic to the local IP instead of the public ones. I don't know if this is information enough, but we can't seem to find the issue since the config of the web app is the same and the IIS didn't seem to have issues. Maybe the DNS? The IP's are the same.

Comment: "... gets wrong IP" vs "The IPs are the same" - talk about confusion. Also, this sounds more like a configuration issue than a programming problem, which is off topic on Stackoverflow (see [help/on-topic])

Comment: What I mean is that the IP's (public and local) are the same between the old and the new servers, but after the upgrade, when we try to reach the web app, it searches for the local IPs.

Comment: No configuration, no details...  Like is there a firewall in the picture?  Could be the arp cache being messed up.  No way to help with what we have.